# Create SQL Server database during application installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have following [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49b92ztk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to create my SQL Server database during installation of my Winforms application. But I got this error :

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name : Stream

Note : my connection string is

```
Data Source=MyServerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

and also my database should create on server.

Please ask me if any thing is unclear...

Comment: where do you receive this error? We need the code where the exception raises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet that the error raises on this row:

```
Stream strm = Asm.GetManifestResourceStream(Asm.GetName().Name + "." + Name);
```

You need to have a file named sql.txt in your project and you need to edit its properties and set its build action to embedded resource

[image]